# How to grep a text recursively on BusyBox 1.0?

Tags: grep, recursive, busybox

How can I find a file containing a certain string on a BusyBox 1.0, if `grep -r` does not work?

Comment: Use find and grep combination. Here is an example - http://wilddiary.com/find-files-containing-my-text/

Answer (score 8):

### `find` plus `grep`

Combine `find` to traverse directories recursively with `grep`.

If support for `-print0` and `-0` are compiled in, then you can use `xargs` to invoke `grep` for many files at once¹:

```
find /some/dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -H PATTERN
```

If your file names are tame (no whitespace or `\'"`), you don't need `-print0`/`-0`:

```
find /some/dir -type f |xargs grep -H PATTERN
```

If you have no suitable `xargs`, you'll need to invoke `grep` on each file name separately:

```
find /some/dir -type f -exec grep -H PATTERN {} \;
```

If you have `find` but it doesn't have `-exec`, and your file names are tame (no newlines or `\[*?`), and your shell supports command substitutions (i.e. ash and not hush), and there aren't too many files to consider, you can generate the list of file names with `find` and pass that as an argument to `grep`.

```
set -f
IFS='
'
grep PATTERN $(find /some/dir -type f)
set +f
```

If there are many files, you can use a `for` loop over all the files (still ash-only because of the command substitution).

```
set -f
IFS='
'
for x in $(find /some/dir -type f); do
  grep -H PATTERN "$x"
done
set +f
```

¹  <sub>No `-exec … +` on Busybox.</sub>

### Without `find`

If you don't have `find`, it gets complicated. If your Busybox has ash and a decent `test`, you can write a recursive directory traversal in the shell.

```
traverse () {
  d=$1; shift
  for x in "$d"/* "$d"/.[!.]* "$d"/..?*; do
    if test -f "$x"; then
      "$@" "$x"
    elif test -d "$x"; then
      traverse "$x" "$@"
    fi
  done
}
traverse /some/dir
```

But if you don't have `find`, you're probably on a very limited system where the shell is hush, which lacks functions. You can simulate functions with `eval`. I'll assume you have `test`; if you don't, detecting directories is possible but painful.

```
command='grep -H PATTERN'
traverse='
  for x in "$d"/* "$d"/.[!.]* "$d"/..?*; do
    if test -f "$x"; then
      '"$command"' "$x"
    elif test -d "$x"; then
      d="$x"
      eval "$traverse"
    fi
  done
'
d=/some/dir
eval "$traverse"
```

Comment: Actually, my BusyBox `find` does accept `-exec ... +`, though it treats it the same as `-exec ... \;`. Not sure if this is a configurable option. Not very useful, but it does make some scripts written for other systems a bit more portable.